# ¿Cómo separo los números pares de un arreglo bidimensional en Java?

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional, numberformat

Estoy haciendo un programa que genere números de manera aleatoria en una matriz de 5x5. Los genera y los muestra correctamente, pero tengo problemas al tratar de separar los números que son pares, también tengo que calcular el promedio de todos los números pares que haya encontrado.

Aquí dejo lo que llevo hasta ahora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tengo dos dudas: ¿Cuál es el problema con ese código? ¿Por qué agregas el código como imagen? En fin, edita la pregunta y añade directamente el código (haz un simple copia y pega). También te invito a leer esto: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema está a la hora de crear los arrays para almacenar los números pares e impares. Los generas con valor 0 y eso te impide almacenar algo en el array.
Te pongo el código que he generado yo con comentarios por si te pueden aclarar mejor el funcionamiento:

```
public class SepararNumerosParesImparesArrayBidimensional {

private static int[][] matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros;
private static int[] arrayNumerosPares;
private static int[] arrayNumerosImpares;


public static void main(String[] args) {

    inicializarArrays(5, 5);
    llenarMatrizConNumerosAleatorios(500);
    creaArrayDeParesEImpares();

    mostarArray(arrayNumerosPares);
    mostarArray(arrayNumerosImpares);

    mostrarPromedioArray(arrayNumerosPares);
    mostrarPromedioArray(arrayNumerosImpares);
}



// Inicializamos el array bidimensional asignándole el valor de las filas
// i el valor de las columnas
// Aprovechamos para inicializar los arrays para los números pares y los números impares.
// el tamaño de estos arrays será igual al tamaño total del array bidimensional.
public static void inicializarArrays(int valorFilas, int valorColumnas) {
    matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros = new int[valorFilas][valorColumnas];
    arrayNumerosPares = new int[valorFilas*valorColumnas];
    arrayNumerosImpares = new int[valorFilas*valorColumnas];
}


// llenamos el array bidimensional con números aleatorios
// con el límite de rango que queramos
// si queremos números aleatorios hasta el numero 500, el limite de rango será de 0 a 500
// si quieres que el rango de números no incluya el 0 añadele +1 al métodp 
// (Math.random() * limiteDeRango + 1)
public static void llenarMatrizConNumerosAleatorios (int limiteDeRango) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros[i].length; j++) {
            matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * limiteDeRango);
        }
    }
}


// creamos los arrays de número pares e impares
// recorremos el array bidimensional y vamos separando los números 
// según sean pares o impares
// para asegurarnos de que no hay espacios vacíos en los arrays creados
// utilizamos el medoto eliminarIndicesVaciosArray() para eliminar dichos índices
public static void creaArrayDeParesEImpares() {

    int contadorIndicesArrayDePares = 0;
    int contadorIndicesArrayDeImpares = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros[i].length; j++) {
            if (matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros[i][j] % 2 == 0) {
                arrayNumerosPares[contadorIndicesArrayDePares] = matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros[i][j];
                contadorIndicesArrayDePares++;
            }else {
                arrayNumerosImpares[contadorIndicesArrayDeImpares] = matrizBidimensionalDeNumeros[i][j];
                contadorIndicesArrayDeImpares++;
            }
        }
    }

    arrayNumerosPares = eliminaIndicesVaciosArray(arrayNumerosPares, contadorIndicesArrayDePares);
    arrayNumerosImpares = eliminaIndicesVaciosArray(arrayNumerosImpares, contadorIndicesArrayDeImpares);
}


// el método retorna un array con los índices vacíos eliminados
// en este caso los arrays para número pares e impares tienen un tamaño de 25,
// con este metodo eliminamos los valores vacios. 
// Ojo! vacio no significa valor 0. Por eso el valor de indiceFinalValido es igual
// al contador de índices utilizados en el método creaArrayDeParesEImpares()
public static int[] eliminaIndicesVaciosArray(int[] arrayAModificar, int indiceFinalValido) {

    int[] arrayTemporal = new int[indiceFinalValido];

    for (int i = 0; i < indiceFinalValido; i++) {
        arrayTemporal[i] = arrayAModificar[i]; 
    }

    return arrayTemporal;

}

//mostramos un array
public static void mostarArray(int[] arrayAMostrar) {

    System.out.println("Valores del array " + tipoDeValoresArray(arrayAMostrar) + ": ");
    System.out.print("|");
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayAMostrar.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arrayAMostrar[i] + "|");
    }

    System.out.println();
}


//calcula y retorna el promedio de un array de enteros
public static double calcularPromedioArray(int[] arrayAProcesar) {
    int sumaNumeros = 0;

    for (int i =  0; i < arrayAProcesar.length; i++) {
        sumaNumeros += arrayAProcesar[i];
    }

    return (double) sumaNumeros / arrayAProcesar.length;
}

// muestra el promedio de un array de enteros
// con printf (%.2f) limitamos el numero a mostrar a 2 decimales
public static void mostrarPromedioArray(int[] arrayAProcesar) {
    System.out.printf("El promedio del array %s es %.2f \n", tipoDeValoresArray(arrayAProcesar), calcularPromedioArray(arrayAProcesar));

}

// genera un String con el tipo de array
public static String tipoDeValoresArray(int[] arrayAProcesar) {
    String tipoArray = "Impar";
    if (arrayAProcesar[0] % 2 == 0) {
        tipoArray = "Par";
    }

    return tipoArray;
}
```

}

Otra cosa que te quería comentar es que a la hora de crear variables, arrays, instancias, clases, métodos, etc... elijas un nombre que identifique claramente la función o el valor de dicha variable, método, clase...
El código que tu has puesto, aún siendo bastante sencillo, me ha costado interpretarlo por culpa de los nombres que has elegido para los arrays, variables y métodos.
No tengas miedo en llamar a una variable: contadorDeNumerosPares, este tipo de nombre te indica claramente la finalidad de dicha variable.

No me enrrollo más, un saludo y espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

No sé muy bien lo que pretendes y no programo en Java, pero veo en el Método Pares() que declaras dos arrays de int con cero elementos. No obstante creo que la sintaxis sería:

int[] par = new int[n];  // Donde n será el tamaño de tu array unidimensional.

Yo lo dimensionaría en 25 que es el número máximo de pares que puede contener la matriz inicial y lo enfocaría así:

```
public void Pares()
{
// La matriz 'mat' es de 5x5 por lo que 25 es el número maximo de elementos.
int[] NumeroClase = new int[25];

for(int ren = 0; ren < 5; ren++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
    {
        // Si el número es par guardo un cero en el array NumeroClase
        // y si es impar guardo un uno.
        NumeroClase[ren * 5 + col] = (mat[ren][col] % 2) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}

// Imprime resultados.
for (int ren = 0; ren < 5; ren++)
{
     for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
     {
     // Miro si el número era par y de serlo lo imprimo
     if (NumeroClase[ren * 5 + col] == 0)          
         system.out.print(mat[ren][col] + "\t");   
     else
         system.out.print("\t");
    }
    system.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn pero considera revisar [answer] , saludos